# How to list the node cron's scheduled jobs

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I am using node-cron package to schedule a job. I wanted to know the internal behavior of it in windows server.
In documentation I can see this

> The actions of cron are driven by a crontab (cron table) file, a configuration file that contains instructions to the cron daemon.

I need to know the internal behavior for documentation purpose. Is anyone share the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cron and node-cron have nothing in common except the job done.

- node-cron is as pure js library
- and cron is a linux service

the sentence you quote seem to come from cron itself while node-cron documentation is here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

in node-cron jobs are not stored in any file. only in memory.

technically : node-cron only uses clever setTimeout to start programmatically registered jobs.

Comment: But that doesn't answer the question - how do you see the jobs scheduled using node-cron.

Comment: since you define the jobs yourself in your source code yçou need to start searching from there. There does not seem to be a method to list registered jobs. you may ask the package maintainer or send a pull request on the repo